# Directional derivative in $(0,0)$

Tags: partial-derivative

Define $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}, \ f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$.

How to prove that all directional derivatives of $f$ in $(0,0)$ exist?

I tried with:

Let $v=(v_1,v_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ with $v_2 \neq 0$.

Then $\partial_vf(0,0)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(hv_1,hv_2)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{h^2v_1v_2}{h(h^2v_1^2+h^2v_2^2)}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{v_1v_2}{h(v_1^2+v_2^2)}$.

Since the denominator is zero, how to continue?

Comment: Why write $f(hv_1,hv_2) = h_2v_1v_2$? Since $f(x,y) = x^2y$, the $h$ should appear three times. Then I think you'll find it works out.

Answer (score 1):

A directional derivative is equivalent to exploit the directions $y = \lambda x$

substituting gives

$$
\frac{\lambda x}{1+\lambda^2}
$$

so as we can observe along a line $y = \lambda x$

$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{\lambda( 0+h)}{1+\lambda^2}-0}{h} = \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda^2}
$$